# Docker ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: node.js, docker, express, server, containers

I have 2 docker containers running on a server:

1. Frontend Vue.js app (0.0.0.0:6336 -> 443/tcp)
2. Express Backend (0.0.0.0:8000 -> 443/tcp)

When the frontend tries to communicate with the backend, with this request:

```
https://host:8000/query
```

I'm getting this error:

> net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

The backend has a certificate applied to it like so:

```
app = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('private_key.key', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.crt', 'utf8')
}, app)
```

If I run both of these apps locally, it works fine. I feel like this is a simple fix but I'm pretty new to Docker so I don't know where to begin.

If I change it to `http`, I get this error:

> xhr.js:178 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://host:6336/#/search?subject=a' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://host:8000/query'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Is express really serving https? If you try `http://host:8000/query`, does that work?

Comment: I updated the question to show what happens with `http`.

Comment: If you access that page directly over http, does that work?

Comment: It does work over http. I've found that if I store the key and cert in the backend repo itself it works, but if they're in a directory that's bound from the host, it doesn't work. And I've verified that the files are there when binding from the host. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: That suggests that Express is really serving http, not https. I've gotten that error before when accessing http resouces using https.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was adding the `listen` statement before the `https` server was created, I didn't realize that the order mattered. Before it was like this:

```
var app = express()

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}...`)
});

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(keyPath, 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(certPath, 'utf8')
}
app = https.createServer(options, app)

return app
```

The `listen` should come after creating the `https` server:

```
var app = express()

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(keyPath, 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(certPath, 'utf8')
}
app = https.createServer(options, app)

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}...`)
});

return app
```